# Segfault due to name collision from third party library

Tags: c++, linker, segmentation-fault, hydra

I'm trying to use a proprietary sdk from sixense (driver for a game controller). It looks like they statically link to boost::thread. My application and some of its dependencies also use boost::thread, and I get a segfault.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7bd1bb5 in boost::thread::start_thread() () from /usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.42.0
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7bd1bb5 in boost::thread::start_thread() () from /usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.42.0
#1  0x00007ffff79869bb in USBDetector::start_hotplug_thread() ()
   from /home/joschu/Downloads/sixenseSDK_linux_OSX/samples/linux_x64/sixense_simple3d/libsixense_x64.so
#2  0x00007ffff7986c7e in USBDetector::start(std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >, std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > >, std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >) () from /home/joschu/Downloads/sixenseSDK_linux_OSX/samples/linux_x64/sixense_simple3d/libsixense_x64.so
#3  0x00007ffff7987298 in USBManagerLinux::start(std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >, std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > >, std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >, int) () from /home/joschu/Downloads/sixenseSDK_linux_OSX/samples/linux_x64/sixense_simple3d/libsixense_x64.so
#4  0x00007ffff79842f3 in USBManager::start(std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >, std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > >, std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >, int) () from /home/joschu/Downloads/sixenseSDK_linux_OSX/samples/linux_x64/sixense_simple3d/libsixense_x64.so
#5  0x00007ffff79a03d6 in DriverMain::start(int) ()
   from /home/joschu/Downloads/sixenseSDK_linux_OSX/samples/linux_x64/sixense_simple3d/libsixense_x64.so
#6  0x00007ffff79a1e32 in sixenseInit ()
   from /home/joschu/Downloads/sixenseSDK_linux_OSX/samples/linux_x64/sixense_simple3d/libsixense_x64.so
#7  0x0000000000400d0d in main () at /home/joschu/bulletsim/src/hydra/hi.cpp:6
```

If I switch around the way the project is linked, I found that my other libraries end up calling sixense's boost::thread.

Is there any way around this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It looks like they statically link to boost::thread

You didn't say what they statically linked `boost::thread` into. I'll assume they linked it into `libsixense_x64.so`.

There are several general ways to avoid the name collision:

1. Ask the sdk developers to clean up their act. What they *should* have done is link boost in statically and *hide* that fact, e.g. by compiling with -fvisibility=hidden, and only exporting their intended interface, rather than exporting *everything* (which is what it sounds they did).
2. If you can't force the sdk developers to clean up, you can load their sdk library via `dlopen` with `RTLD_LOCAL` binding. This makes it a little awkward to use the sdk, but should keep its symbols from the global dynamic linker namespace.
3. Finally, for completeness: if you are on Linux (which your message suggests but does not state), you can use `dlmopen` to load the sdk into a completely separate dynamic linker namespace. I don't see any advantage compared to option 2, and there are several disadvantages.

Comment: That's right, they linked it into libsixense_x64.so, which exports everything. Thanks for the thorough answer.